# C# Queue Latest Asynchronous Task

Tags: wpf, task-parallel-library

I'm working on a WPF application in which I need to perform a lengthy operation whenever a property that's data-bound to a slider changes. Is there a simple way to queue asynchronous tasks for this operation, but ensure that only the most recently queued task runs?

Comment: Are you asking how to *throttle* the events fired by the slider? That's different than queueing. .NET has mechanisms that allow you to queue data for processing ([ActionBlock<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx)), keep only one of them for processing ([BroadcastBlock<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447(v=vs.110).aspx) or throttle a stream of events so only one every X or T seconds passes through [Observable.Throttle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400(v=vs.103).aspx). These are *different. I'd say you want throttling

Comment: Throttling does indeed sound like a good solution. Are you able to provide an example of how I would implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by creating a task chain using `Task.ContinueWith()`. A thread-safe counter ensures that only the last task in the chain actually runs.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class AsyncTaskRunner
    {
        #region Member Variables

        Task m_TaskChain;
        int m_TaskCount;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public AsyncTaskRunner()
        {
            //Initialize the member variables
            m_TaskChain = Task.CompletedTask;
            m_TaskCount = 0;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public void Run(Action action)
        {
            //Add a continuation to the task chain using the specified action
            Interlocked.Increment(ref m_TaskCount);
            m_TaskChain = m_TaskChain.ContinueWith((prevTask) =>
            {
                //Call the action if we're the last task in the task chain
                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_TaskCount) == 0)
                {
                    action();
                }
            });
        }

        public async Task WaitAsync()
        {
            //Wait for the asynchronous task chain to finish
            await m_TaskChain;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a single task, cancel it, then reassign it with a new one. The task can be chained with a delay to debounce the slider:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancel;
Task task;
...

cancel?.Cancel();
cancel?.Dispose();
cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
task = Task.Delay(3000, cancel.Token).ContinueWith(...);
```

Comment: In this case the lengthy task is pushing data to a device, so canceling it is going to have nasty side effects.

Comment: @NeilThiessen I've edited my answer so it cancels only the delay task.

Comment: You can also delay the update of the binding, by adding a [`Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to it.  This is useful for properties that can change their value rapidly.  The the delay timer starts on the first update, but will only actually update the backing property once the timer completes, but it will be updated with the *latest* value.  You can use it like this `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Delay=500}"/>`

Comment: @BradleyUffner The delay timer resets every time the value changes, so in your example the slider needs to pause for 500ms before the property is updated. I need the property to update as fast as possible, and my long running task to also run as fast as possible albeit asynchronously. Please see the answer I just posted for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`Delay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to the `Binding` that does this.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/whats-new#delay) specifically calls out `Slider` as a good candidate for using it:

> If you use a data binding to update a data source, you can use the
>   Delay property to specify an amount of time to pass after the property
>   changes on the target before the source updates. For example, suppose
>   that you have a Slider that has its Value property data two-way bound
>   to a property of a data object and the UpdateSourceTrigger property is
>   set to PropertyChanged. In this example, when the user moves the
>   Slider, the source updates for each pixel that the Slider moves. The
>   source object typically needs the value of the slider only when the
>   slider's Value stops changing. To prevent updating the source too
>   often, use Delay to specify that the source should not be updated
>   until a certain amount of time elapses after the thumb stops moving.

It can be used like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Delay=500}"/>
```

Comment: I need the long running task to run as fast as it can while the slider is changing. `Delay` just prevents the binding from updating until the slider stops moving...